# computing the distribution over the latent function values with the form of a GP predictive

Tags: gaussian-process, posterior, hierarchical-bayesian, state-space-models

If we have a latent state space $\mathbf{X}$ and the observations $\mathbf{Y}$ and the transition function between two states $\mathbf{x}_{t-1}$ and $\mathbf{x}_{t}$ is given by $\mathbf{f}$ which is a gaussian process with mean function $m_f$ and covariance $k_f$, where its graphical model is as follows:

[image]

The generative model is given by
$$f(x)\sim\mathcal{GP}(m_f(\mathbf{x}),k_f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}'))\\
\mathbf{x}_0\sim p(\mathbf{x}_0)\\
\mathbf{f}_t=f(\mathbf{x}_{t-1})\\
\mathbf{x}_{t}|\mathbf{f}_{t}\sim\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{f}_{t},\mathbf{Q})\\
\mathbf{y}_t|\mathbf{x}_t\sim p(\mathbf{y}_t|\mathbf{x}_t,\boldsymbol{\theta}_y)$$

I would like to know how the following probability can be rederived
$$\mathbf{f}_2|\mathbf{f}_1,\mathbf{x}_{0:1}\sim\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{f}_2|m_f(\mathbf{x}_1)+k_f(\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_0)k_f(\mathbf{x}_0,\mathbf{x}_0)^{-1}(\mathbf{f}_1-m_f(\mathbf{x}_0)),k_f(\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_1)-k_f(\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_0)k_f(\mathbf{x}_0,\mathbf{x}_0)^{-1}k_f(\mathbf{x}_0,\mathbf{x}_1))$$
Thanks!

Comment: According to the specification of your generative model, $\mathbf{f}_2$ is a deterministic function of $\mathbf{x}_1$, so the "distribution" of $\mathbf{f}_2 | \mathbf{f}_1, \mathbf{x}_{0:1}$ would just be a point-mass on $\mathbf{f}_2 = f(\mathbf{x}_1)$.  I take it this is not what you intended for the question?

Comment: @Ben note that $f$ itself is a random function, so $\mathbf{f}_2$ is random even when $\mathbf{x}_1$ is fixed.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I missed that bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume a Gaussian Process prior on the function values,
$$P(f_1|\mathbf{x}_1)\sim\mathcal{GP}(m_f(\mathbf{x}_1),k_f(\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_1))$$
then for the new state, we have
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    f_1\\
    f_2\\
     \end{bmatrix}
=\mathcal{N}\Bigg(
\begin{bmatrix}
    m_f(\mathbf{x}_1) \\
    m_f(\mathbf{x}_2)\\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
    k_f(\mathbf{x}_0,\mathbf{x}_0)       & k_f(\mathbf{x}_0,\mathbf{x}_1) \\
    k_f(\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_0)       & k_f(\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_1) \\
\end{bmatrix}\Bigg)
$$
the conditional distribution of $f_2$ given $f_1$ is itself Gaussian-distributed, we can use the Schur complement and write this as
$$f_2|f_1\sim\mathcal{N}(m_f(\mathbf{x}_1)+k_f(\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_0)k_f(\mathbf{x}_0,\mathbf{x}_0)^{-1}(f_1-m_f(\mathbf{x}_0)),k_f(\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_1)-k_f(\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_0)k_f(\mathbf{x}_0,\mathbf{x}_0)^{-1}k_f(\mathbf{x}_0,\mathbf{x}_1))$$